# SSIS Project : [File] cannot be opened or loaded because it has already been opened or loaded in another project or solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I am trying to open a Visual Studio solution file named [`SSIS Local Project.sln`] with an SSIS project named [`IsolatedPackages.dtproj`]. I receive an error message (seenn below), and the project fails to load.  I am not sure how to fix this error message.

Does anyone know what is happening and how I can get the project to successfully load the packages?

> C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\SSISPackages\Local
>   Project\IsolatedPackages\IsolatedPackages.dtproj : error  :
>   'C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\SSISPackages\Local
>   Project\IsolatedPackages\Project.params' cannot be opened or loaded
>   because it has already been opened or loaded in another project or
>   solution.

I looked in the solution file structure and found the file [`Project.params`] 8 different times.  See screenshots below.

**Solution Explorer**:

IsolatedPackages-Project.params (cannot be opened).png

[image]

Comment: The `Project.params` that it is trying to load would be in the same folder as the `.dtproj` file and all of the `.dtsx` files. It sounds like something has it locked. Can you temporarily rename it to see if it is locked?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I have renamed the file `...\IsolatedPackages\Project.params` to `...\IsolatedPackages\Project-(renamed).params`.  I then tried to reload the project.  I still get the same error message-- `"error : 'C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\SSISPackages\Local Project\IsolatedPackages\Project.params' cannot be opened or loaded because it has already been opened or loaded in another project or solution"`.  The project against says "load failed".

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - To add to the previous comment, I noticed that when I choose "Reload Project" the filed Project.params is created automatically and I have the renamed file and the problematic file.  So I have more files now.

Comment: I've had this error in the past when I forgot to Stop a package that was running in Visual Studio and attempted to open the solution on another workstation.

Comment: @KeithL - Wow, that's bizarre.  Well I'm thinking instead of fixing this project, I'm just going to move the package to a new project.  Were you able to resolve the issue with the project not loading?

Comment: The solution was to stop the running package. And then everything just opened.